# Parenthesis vs curly braces

Tags: c++, constructor

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class test
{
    public:
    int a,b;

    test()
    {
        cout<<"default construictor";

    }
    test(int x,int y):a(x),b(y){

        cout<<"parmetrized constructor";
    }

};
int main()
{

    test t;
    cout<<t.a;
     //t=(2,3);->gives error
     t={2,3}; //calls paramterized constructor
     cout<<t.a;
}
```

Output:- default construictor4196576parmetrized constructor2

why in case of the above example, parameterized constructor(even though default constructor is already called.) is called in case of {} and not in ()

Comment: Are you using C++11?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I added some additional code to show what is actually happening.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class test
{
    public:
    int a,b;

    test()
    {
        cout << "default constructor" << endl;
    }

    ~test()
    {
        cout << "destructor" << endl;
    }

    test(int x,int y):a(x),b(y)
    {
        cout << "parameterized constructor" << endl;
    }

    test& operator=(const test& rhs)
    {
        a = rhs.a;
        b = rhs.b;
        cout << "assignment operator" << endl;
        return *this;
    }

};

int main()
{

    test t;
    cout << t.a << endl;
     //t=(2,3);->gives error
     t={2,3}; //calls parameterized constructor
     cout << t.a << endl;
}
```

Output:

```
default constructor
4197760
parameterized constructor
assignment operator
destructor
2
destructor
```

So the statement `t={2,3};` is actually constructing a new `test` object using the parameterized constructor, calling the assignment operator to set `t` to be equal to the new, temporary `test` object, and then destroying the temporary `test` object. It's equivalent to the statement `t=test(2,3)`.

Comment: because `(2,3)`is not valid c++ code, `{2,3}` is a list. see a c++ book like @Aldwin Cheung suggested

Answer (score 4):

use

```
test t(2,3);
```

instead of

```
test t;
t=(2,3);
```

Because parentheses are used after object declaration.